# Triple integral of a vector

Tags: integration

I want to calculate this integral, but I dont know how:
$$\int\int\int_\text{whole space}3(\vec{r}+2\vec{a})^2\delta^3(\vec{r}-\vec{a})d\tau,$$
With $\vec{a}$ a fixed vector and $\delta$ the Dirac delta function?

Comment: the delta function will pull out the value of the integrand at $\vec a$

Comment: I dont get why my question is being downvoted. I really dont understand this question and I was looking for some help

Comment: What have you tried? What do you already know about the delta function in say one dimension?

Comment: I dont understand it at all, thats the problem

Comment: Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: In one dimension, we can use the delta function like this:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a)dx=f(a)$$
i.e. the delta function "pulls out" the value of the integrated function $f(x)$ at the particular value $x=a$, giving just $f(a)$.

In three dimensions (here Cartesian coordinates, but this only affects the limits and the volume element) you would have to be integrating over all space:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\vec r)\delta^3(\vec r-\vec a)d^3\vec r=f(\vec a)$$

Comment: Does that give $27\vec{a}$ as final answer?

Comment: almost: the bracket seems to be squared...

Comment: So $27\vec{a}^2$?

Comment: I got $27a^2$...

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant

Comment: I get what you did, but could you show me the steps? Triple integrals and vectors are kinda new to me

Comment: not many steps but I have amended my answer above